# Foreign Keys and Data Import

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, phpmyadmin

I have:

- a CSV file (5000+ records);
- an empty `item` table;
- am empty `favourite` table;
- a number of other empty tables.

I would like to populate the `item` table with the contents of the CSV file. Then I would like to create some foreign key relationships between both tables.

In what order do I do this?

I keep receiving an error every time I attempt this:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...
```

Note that my empty `favourite` table already has some foreign key constraints set up. I am using PhpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench.

Am I supposed to have all the tables populated with data **before** I set up foreign key relationships? Or do I set up the relationships then populate with data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several choices. You can either create the tables without the constraints & add them afterwards, or create the tables with the foreign keys & them import the data with foreign key checks disabled - simply run `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in your `mysql` session to temporarily disable them.

For example:

```
mysql> insert into favourite values( 1,1);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tmp`.`favourite`, CONSTRAINT `favourite_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `item` (`item_id`))
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into favourite values( 1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks @Philᵀᴹ - I read on a few other discussions it's not advisable to turn off foreign key checks as it can lead to data inconsistencies?

Comment: @johnny_s Yeah, it can. Easy to write some validation SQL scripts though.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE ...
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE ...
mysql> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim - can you explain what's going on in your answer?

Comment: Disabling foreign key checks for the session, loading the data, and re-enabling foreign key checks.  That should prevent FK errors as you load the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using terminal, login to MySQL using your credentials with the following command:

```
mysql -u[your_username] -p[your_password]
```

Set your MySQL foreign key constraint checks to `0` using the next command:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Import your database using a source command like the one below:

```
SOURCE /path/to/your/sql/file.sql
```

And set your MySQL foreign key constraint checks back to `1` using the command that follows:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

P.S. Tested on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04